# $\mathrm{Sp}_n(q)$-conjugacy classes in $\mathrm{GL}_{2n}(q)$

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, symplectic-group, conjugacy-classes

The symplectic group $\mathrm{Sp}_n(q)$  acts on $\mathrm{GL}_{2n}(q)$ by conjugation. All the literature I have found concerning the orbits of action of this kind is *"Unipotent conjugacy classes in general linear groups"* by Alperin, which is not really about what I am looking for.

Is there any work referring to this action and its orbits?

Comment: Do you mean $Sp_n(q)$ or $Sp_{2n}(q)$? The first is a subgroup of $GL_n(q)$ while the second is a subgroup of $GL_{2n}(q)$.